# How can I group text questions that are similar to each other?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I have a dataset of 200k questions, and I would like to group them together by similarity/duplicates.

How can I use NLP/machine learning to group these questions with similar intents together?

Given a question and a list of questions, how can I find the question or questions that are similar or duplicates?

Are there any services that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you'd want to convert the questions into a abstract numerical format (such as a single high-dimensional vector, or 'bags of words/vectors'), from which it is then possible to calculate numerical pairwise similarities between questions.

For example: you could turn each question into a simple average of the word-vectors for its individual words. (Those word-vectors might come from your own training corpus, that matches the questions' usage domain exactly, or from some other outside source that's good enough.)

If the word-vectors are 300-dimensional, averaging all the words-vectors of a question together then gives you a 300-dimensional vector for the question. You can then use a typical measure of vector-similarity, such as "cosine similarity", to get a number from -1.0 to 1.0 for each pair of questions, with larger values indicating "more similar".

Such a simple approach is often a good baseline. Being smarter about dropping some words, or weighting words by their observed significance (eg by "TF/IDF" weighting) may improve it.

But there are other ways to get summary vectors that may work better than a simple average. One relatively straightforward algorithm, largely similar to the way word-vectors are created, is called "Paragraph Vectors", and is sometimes called in popular libraries (like Python gensim) "Doc2Vec". It's not quite a simple average of word-vectors, as much as creating a synthetic word-like token for a full text, which then is trained to be as good as possible at predicting the text's words. Again, once you have a (for example) 300-dimensional text-vector, calculating cosine-similarity can rank question similarities.

There's also an interesting algorithm called "Word Mover's Distance", which leaves the texts as variable-sized bags of each constituent word-vector, as if each word-vector was a pile-of-meaning. It then calculates the "effort" to move the piles from one text's shape-of-piles, to another text's – and less effort seems to correlate well with humans' sense of text similarity. (However, finding these minimal-shifts is a *lot* more computationally expensive than simple cosine-similarity – so this works best with short texts, or small corpuses, or when you can massively parallelize the computation.)

Once you have any of these numeric-similarity measures working, then you can also clustering algorithms to find groups of highly-related questions – and often once you have those groups, the most-common words in those groups (as opposed to others), or human editorial work, can name the groups.